# TYPO3 - Change website language in frontend?

Tags: web, frontend, typo3

Is it possible to change the website language in my frontend templates?
I want to have a list or a dropdown of all website languages i have created in my TYPO3 backend.

On click, I want to show my page in the chosen language.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is eminently do-able in TYPO3 (I've done it on several sites myself). The [Frontend Localization Guide](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/FrontendLocalizationGuide/) is the document that shows you how -- give it a read-through and you'll be on your way.

Answer (score 0):

Once you configure the languages in Typo3
Try this extension, it will help you

http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/sr_language_menu/current/